# Working with emoji in editable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, emoji

I'm using [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) library to display emoji in input field (contanteditable div):

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="input_div"></div>
```

user can add emoji using external button so I can add it to div quite simply (lets don't care about caret position):

```
div.innerHTML += twemoji.parse(emoji);
```

next I need to get user input from the div with emoji, is there some simple way to convert  back into unicode chars?

my current solution [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/02uTZtNcGekH1fucmviC?p=preview) (I just parse `<img>` to get alt attribute) but I think it looks a bit tricky and I can't use `div.innerText` property (quite convenient to get plain text from div) because I'll lost emojis. Also I'm using `div.getInnerText` to prevent inserting html or images from the clipboard:

```
div.addEventListener("insert", () => {setTimeout(div.innerText = div.innerText,0)})
```

Comment: You’ll get something like this back as the innerHTML of the editable element, `<img class="emoji" draggable="false" alt="" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f600.png">` – so you could parse it out of the img src again (seeing as `1F600` is the code point you create the emoji from, so that seems to be directly reflected in the image file name.)

Comment: @CBroe please refer my link on plunker that is exactly I do now (I parse alt attribute but it doesn't matter), and for me it looks inconvenient since I am using div.innerText property to get clean text from div without any html

Comment: _“I parse alt attribute but it doesn't matter”_ - it does matter, if the alt attribute does not contain what you want. `alt=""` – see that replacement character there? (That’s copied from simply logging the innerHTML to console.) That most likely means what the library you are using has written into the attribute is not a valid unicode codepoint. (I see exactly that same character under your textarea once I click the "get text" button – so your code works, it just works on input data that was corrupted already.)

Comment: @CBroe alt attribute doesn't contains unicode codepoint but it contains surrogate symbols which should correspond this codepoint and as far as I know in this case there is no difference between using codepoint and group of \u chars, isn't it? Just to be sure, in your comment I see emoji symbol which corresponds `1F607` codepoint. I checked it on OSX and Windows7/10 with standard fonts

Comment: @CBroe it seems I don't understand you correctly, what did you mean " it just works on input data that was corrupted already."?

Comment: Log the innerHTML to console, and look at how the content of the alt attribute is displayed.

Comment: @CBroe I see an emoji char in browser console too so I still don't understand what do you want to say. Yes it is not a codepoint but it is a valid char which is written as `\uD83D\uDE00`

Comment: Sorry, I only see the unicode replacement character, and not an actual emoji. But anyway, you will either have to parse the information out of what you get from the editable element’s innerHTML – or you need to store the info where/at what position you inserted which emoji while you are doing so.

Comment: OK, it seems to be clear now, so is there some reason not to use replacement char instead of codepoint since browser will convert it anyway?

Comment: @CBroe could you tell me what OS/browser do you use? and if it is possible could you also provide a scree capture of your console?

Comment: Current Chrome on Win 7. http://i.stack.imgur.com/V8DX9.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122744/discussion-between-leo-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 4):

So I created a working editable div with a beautiful twemoji tab, just like WhatsApp!

I edited the Twemoji script a bit to make it work perfect. LOT OF WORK dude!

**So here is the [fidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqc7a1bh/1/)**

and the code to convert the unicode to a twemoji image and to switch tabs:

```
  function convert() {
    document.body.innerHTML = twemoji.parse(document.body.innerHTML);
  }
  convert();

  $(document).delegate('.emoji-header button', 'click', function() {
    index = $(this).index()
    $('.emoji-panel').css({
      'transform': 'translateX(-' + index + '00%)'
    });
  });

  $('.emoji-panel .emojicon').on('click', function() {
    $('.message').append($('img', this).clone());
  });
  $('.message').on('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

Happy coding, great question by the way!

Comment: Looks great! But I found a small issue which can cause some troubles when parse entered message, just add `.emojicon {font-size: 35px;}` to css and try to enter text right after an emoji char (it because of div.emojicon don't know why do you need it). Also it still is not an answer for the original question, at least I don't see it, how do you suggest to send a message after click button?

Comment: You must understand that an unicode character coverted to an image is not affected by font-size. So if the editable div has let's say `font-size 18px`, you could add `.emojicon {height: 1em; width: 1em;}` to css and you fixed that issue. For sending the message just use php or ajax, make sure the field has charset utf-8, when fetching this content from the database simply use the convert() function in this answer

Comment: Sure, but the text which you enter near the `.emojicon div` is affected by its font-size and actually is being inserted into the `div.emojicon` and could make message parsing more complicated. To solve it need to specify `contenteditable=false` for `div.emojicon`. When I was saying 'how to sand' I mean that I still need somehow to convert text with emoji imgs into string, the original question is about such convertation

Comment: You can do that with php or ajax, parsing a piece of code, text with tags or script into a string. There are solutions everywhere on the web; use htmlentities(string) to put it into your database, use html_entity_decode(string) when you fetch it again. (this is php, but they have jquery functions for these as well) Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: Looks great, I found a small issue on clicking on emojis caret is not showing before or after the images which will be little difficult if want to place some content or emoji in between. If you have any solution please let me know. thanks..

Comment: @user1162084 it's a really long time ago, but I think this might be able to help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection